# Blur Background When Popup Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to blur the background when I click on an image and it popup.
I already have it where it blurs a section of the page. However, you can see anything that is outside of that section not blur-out.

CSS

```
.content2#blur.active{ 
filter: blur(20px);
pointer-events: none;
user-select: none;}

#popup{  /*NEW*/
position: fixed;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 600px;
padding: 50px;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup.active{ 
width: 650px;
top: 53%;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
transition: 0.5s;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="port" id="pLink">
    <div class="heading" id="blur">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content2" id="blur">
        <div class="pBox">
        <a href="#" class="anchor" onclick="toggle()" id="img-1">
            <img src="../mywebsite/img/bp.jpg">
            <div class="overlay">
            <h5>Image Description</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div id="popup">
        <a href="#" class="anchor" onclick="toggle()">
        <img src="../mywebsite/img/bp.jpg" class="img-1">
   </div>
</section>

<div class="footer">
    <p>Copyright</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggle(){
var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
blur.classList.toggle('active');
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
popup.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

I tried adding the same `id="blur"` to the footer but the problem is that it only works for one `<div>`.
I also tried adding a separate css code for let say `class="footer" but it doesn't work.

```
.footer#blur.active{ 
 filter: blur(20px);
 pointer-events: none;
 user-select: none;}
```

I also tried moving the id tag to the section, but that only blurs the heading not the rest.

Comment: Id should be unique. Try wrapping everything in a div and only blurring that div.

Comment: I tried that. It only blurs everything including the popup image.

Comment: Take the popup out of that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to add a "blur" class to anyone element you want to get the effect when the image is clicked.

**The changes I made:**

Change in **CSS** `#blur` to `.blur`

**JS** - The function takes all elements with class `.blur` and has add or remove class `.active`

**HTML** - added classes `.blur` to all elements that need to be blurred.

*In one document you can have many classes with the same name, but you can have only one element with a unique ID! This is the reason I change the `blur` from ID to CLASS*

```js
function toggle() {
    var blur = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
   
    for (var i = 0; i < blur.length; i++) {
        blur[i].classList.toggle('active');
    }

    var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.blur.active {
    filter: blur(2px);
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#popup {
    /*NEW*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 600px;
    padding: 50px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup.active {
    width: 650px;
    top: 53%;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<section class="port" id="pLink">
    <div class="heading blur">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content2 blur">
        <div class="pBox">
            <a href="#" class="anchor" onclick="toggle()" id="img-1">
                <img src="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/horse-galloping-close-up-action-photography_by_54ka-165x165.jpg">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h5>Image Description</h5>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <a href="#" class="anchor" onclick="toggle()">
            <img src="https://blog.54ka.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/horses_XI_01_by_54ka.jpg" class="img-1">
    </div>
</section>


<div class="footer blur">
    <p>Copyright</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I did everything exactly. There are two problems I encounter.
1. When clicking the image it doesn't do anything. 2. The image itself is larger and not in the same location I had it before and it covers the whole page.

Comment: Everything works on the example I uploaded! It is important to put the JS code at the bottom of the page!

Comment: I do have the js code. Still, nothing is working for me. Originally the way I had it was working almost perfectly except that it was only working for one div and not the rest. Like you mentioned only one id should be unique. I tried it with class but instead it doesn't even popup and blur anything.

Comment: Upload your project somewhere I can see it

Comment: 1. The JS code you use is not the one I posted!!! 2. You cannot use classes this way -> `<div class="content2" class="blur">` has to be `<div class="content2 blur">`. This is at first glance ... Please review your error code!